Gnome session refreshing often
My Ubuntu 24.04 LTS machine is having a problem with the session.
The session (all open apps, terminal windows, etc.) closes itself after a longer period of suspension both when I close the laptop lid & when I just let it go into sleep mode on it's own.
The session also refreshes when I disconnect the laptop from a docking station (most likely due to the monitor disconnect).
Is this an issue or is this expected behaviour? I'd like the session to not refresh unless I specifically log out my session or restart the machine.
